# mac eclipse android phonegap with sqlite database autoincrement and maxid retreivel

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

im actually dotnet developer now im starting to develop mobile application using eclipse android and phonegap i have studied these in docs.phonegap.com i find no difficulty in examples ie camera device and accelerometer. I have successfully connected to database now my question is how can i applay autoincrement in create table and retreive ( max id +1) from database the given code is not working

 **my code is**

 **Javascript code#**

```
     function onDeviceReady() {
            var db = window.openDatabase('dbNexTrainer','1.0', 'NexTrainer',2 * 1024 * 1024);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }
function populateDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_Excercise  (ExId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,ExName ,ExDescription ,ExPreCondition ,ExImage ,IsActive INTEGER,AddDate DATE)');
tx.executeSql('Delete from tbl_Excercise');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tbl_Excercise  VALUES (1,"Excercise 1","Description 1","Pre Condition 1","image/image1.png",1,"12/09/2012 01:00:00")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tbl_Excercise  VALUES (2,"Excercise 2","Description 2","Pre Condition 2","image/image2.jpg",1,"12/09/2012 01:00:00")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tbl_Excercise  VALUES (3,"Excercise 3","Description 3","Pre Condition 3","image/image3.jpg",1,"12/09/2012 01:00:00")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tbl_Excercise  VALUES (4,"Excercise 4","Description 4","Pre Condition 4","image/image4.jpg",1,"12/09/2012 01:00:00")');
```

second problem how to retrieve max id

 **Javascript Code**

```
   function NewExcercise(){
     var db = window.openDatabase('dbNexTrainer','1.0', 'NexTrainer',2 * 1024 * 1024);
          db.transaction(GetNewExId, errorCB);    
    }
var  GetNewExId=function(tx) 
       {
           var db = window.openDatabase('dbNexTrainer','1.0', 'NexTrainer',2 * 1024 * 1024);
          var sql = "SELECT MAX(ExId)+1 as ExId FROM tbl_Excercise";
           tx.executeSql(sql, [], ReturnNewId, errorCB); 
           return  window.localStorage.getItem('NewExId') 
      }

      var  ReturnNewId  = function(transaction, results) {
   try{       
         var row = results.rows.item(i);          
         window.localStorage.setItem('NewExId', row['ExId']);            
    }
    catch(e){
    alert(e);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in CREATE TABLE syntax, you need to define the data types for all the table fields,

try this statement,

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_Excercise  (ExId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,ExName TEXT ,ExDescription TEXT ,ExPreCondition TEXT ,ExImage BLOB ,IsActive INTEGER,AddDate DATE)');
```

Comment: create table works fine just how do i autoincrement in query and retreive maxid

Comment: `SELECT MAX(ExId) as ExId FROM tbl_Excercise`

Comment: yes im dead sure its working fine without defining columns i hava only define isavtice integer and adddate as Date

Comment: @skhurams, you can ommitte that field and write insert query like this  insert into  tbl_Excercise  ( fields names... ) values ( values );

Comment: what you wrote ( code ) , can you show me the statement pls ?

Comment: tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_Excercise  (ExId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,ExName TEXT ,ExDescription TEXT ,ExPreCondition TEXT ,ExImage BLOB ,IsActive INTEGER,AddDate DATE)');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tbl_Excercise  (ExName  ,ExDescription  ,ExPreCondition  ,ExImage ,IsActive,AddDate)')  VALUES ("Excercise 1","Description 1","Pre Condition 1","image/image1.png",1,"12/09/2012 01:00:00")'); //here i have omitted ExId so it should add it automatically